# Error: apt-get install msodbcsql

Tags: sql-server, odbc, ubuntu-16.04

When I execute the following in the terminal:

```
#sudo apt-get install msodbcsql
```

I get the following error:

> Installation Failed, ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server Detected!

I tried to reinstall following this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server-on-linux

but I still get the same error.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Debian with Ubuntu packages for mssql server. I had the same problem trying to reinstall mssql-tools, the message:

```
Installation Failed, ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server Detected!
```

**The solution:**
In file `/etc/odbcinst.ini` delete the following lines:

```
[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.8.0
UsageCount=1
```

Finally, I did `apt -f install` and problem solved.

Answer (score 5):

To solve this i did a couple of things:

1. I removed the contents of `/etc/odbcinst.ini` as suggested by Sebastian
2. I stopped the mssql-server service `sudo systemctl stop mssql-server`I don't know if this was necessary, but fiddling with tools related to it, it seemed the decent thing to do.
3. I did `sudo apt remove mssql-tools`
4. Then `sudo apt remove msodbcsql` The mssqlodbc part appended by whatever version number
5. Then `sudo apt install mssql-tools`this will install the newest version of `mssql-tools` for which `msodbcsql` is a requirement and thus it will itself fetch the required (newest i should think) version of that package. At this point, the problem has been fixed, The Sql service should still be started though
6. `sudo systemctl start mssql-server`

And thus everything was fine for me again.

Please notice that i did this in elementary OS 0.4 Loki.

Comment: On Xenial, this worked for me, except I replaced `mssqlodbc` with `msodbcsql`

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to install ODBC 13 but had a very similar error

> Installation Failed, ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server Detected!

I had to:

```
sudo apt-get remove unixodbc mssql-tools odbcinst libodbc1
```

manually install the package apt had downloaded (I found it in /var/cache/apt/archives/msodbcsql_13.1.4.0-1_amd64.deb)

```
sudo dpkg -i msodbcsql_13.1.4.0-1_amd64.deb
ldd /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-*
```

then you can reinstall unixodbc, mssql-tools, libodbc1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove unixODBC before the installation could complete successfully.

MS were serious when they said "yum remove unixODBC #to avoid conflicts"

I had otherwise followed MS removal instructions for msodbc 11 prior to installing 13. (RedHat 7 intructions applied to Fedora 25 - DNF instead of YUM)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered I needed to remove `/usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini` too. With that config file in place I kept getting the "Installation Failed, ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server Detected!" error.

Thus:

```
$ sudo bash
# apt-get remove unixodbc mssql-tools odbcinst libodbc1
# rm /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
# apt-get -f install
# sudo dpkg -i msodbcsql_13.1.4.0-1_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

> Installation Failed, ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server Detected!

If you've installed package with registration option (which is by default), remove the driver by:

```
odbcinst -u -d -n "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server"
```

Eventually locate your driver's ini file by: `odbcinst -j` and remove the driver section manually.

See: [Installing the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux and macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server)